# .document() does not seem to work in a specific part of my flutter code

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am working on a flutter project with firebase, for some reason .document() does not seem to work for me in the code below. Why is that?

Thank You :)

```
await Firestore.instance.collection(('Foods').document(food.name).delete());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new releases of firebase packages there are some breaking changes such as 'document' has been renamed to `doc`.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('Foods').doc(food.name).delete());
```

Comment: ref this https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I still an error. Here is what the error says: "Error: The method 'doc' isn't defined for the class 'String'. "

Comment: try to update to latest firebase dependencies